# compare local and server database table data in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee

I want to fetch database from a server and then compare the database to another database and then insert or update accordingly which is not same using java.

```
  databse A

Table A
----------
Id  NAME
1    AAA
2    BBB
3    CCC
```

```
databse B
Table A
----------
Id  NAME
1    AAA
2    FFF
```

```
Then the table B will be
```

```
databse B
Table A
----------
Id  NAME  **operation** 
1    AAA  **No action will happen**
2    BBB  **Update** 
3    CCC   **insert**
```

The following example will be will be output. The updated table will contain the synchronized data.

look in Database B Table A only update those thing that are updated
Also keep in mind that 2 database are in 2 different machine.

Comment: I'm not a wiz with databases so this may be wrong in this case, but wouldn't SQL set functions work for you here? Like UNION for example.

Comment: The final table A in DB B is just a copy of table A in DB A. Is this really what you want? Or is row `2 FFF` missing?

Comment: Maybe something like this:
SELECT * FROM A.dbo.TableA
UNION
SELECT * FROM B.dbo.TableB